# How can 'yield' be added as a keyword in ES6 if it wasn't a reserved word?

Tags: javascript, es6

`yield` is not a [reserved word](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Reserved_Words) in JavaScript, yet ES6 makes it a keyword.

I thought the point of reserved words was for backwards compatibility. For example, `let` and `const` were reserved, so you couldn't use those words as variable names in your ES5 code. That ensures that your ES5 code will run fine in an ES6 engine.

...but what if you used `yield` as a variable name? Why was this word not reserved? And if it doesn't matter, then why were *any* words reserved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In ECMAScript 5, `yield` is a strict-mode "[Future Reserved Word](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1.2)":

> **7.6.1.2 Future Reserved Words**
>
> The following words are used as keywords in proposed extensions and are therefore reserved to allow for the possibility of future adoption of those extensions.
>
> ...
>
> ```
> class enum    extends super
> const export  import
> ```
>
> The following tokens are also considered to be *FutureReservedWords* when they occur within strict mode code (see 10.1.1). The occurrence of any of these tokens within strict mode code in any context where the occurrence of a *FutureReservedWord* would produce an error must also produce an equivalent error:
>
> ```
> implements  let      private    public  yield
> interface   package  protected  static
> ```

This means that in non-strict code, your concerns are correct: the correctness of the line `var yield = 5;` will differ in non-strict mode between an ES5 and ES6 implementation. However, in strict mode, the line is invariably invalid for both ES5 and ES6. This means that you should use strict mode whenever possible to maximize forward compatibility of your ES5 code.

As for *why* yield was not fully reserved for non-strict code, I assume this was done to bridge compatibility between ES3, which did not include `yield` as a *FutureReservedWord* (see [ES3 section 7.5.3, on page 14](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf)). In order to introduce `yield`, the commitee had to break compatibility somewhere, either in the 3-to-5 transition or the 5-to-6 transition. However, some reserved words that were included in ES3 were downgraded to strict-mode reserved words in ES5. I do not know the rationale for that decision.